# Can't install Midnight Commander

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

How do I install "Double Commander" or "Midnight Commander" file managers in Ubuntu 18.04?

I tried to install Midnight Commander with `sudo apt-get install mc` but got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mc is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'mc' has no installation candidate
```

Is there some working file managers for Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Midnight Commander is in the repos, what messages do you get when you try and do `sudo apt-get install mc`?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mc' has no installation candidate

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mc`.  It sounds like your system doesn't know what's available in the repositories.  Once it finishes its "Update" task, it should then be able to install `mc`

Comment: Maybe the universe repo isn't enabled?

Comment: @DKBose it's enabled by default since a long time ago.  More likely they just installed and haven't done an `apt-get update` yet

Comment: FYI: Double Commander [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=doublecmd&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) are named `doublecmd-gtk` and `doublecmd-qt`.

Comment: for  Ubuntu Server this helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071392/ubuntu-18-04-1-mc

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Midnight Commander and Double Commander are already in the 18.04 repos, you just have to install it.

Judging by the errors you're getting, however, your system doesn't know that `mc` is actually installable and doesn't know what packages are available, so start with an update and then try and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mc
```

You can install Double Commander by replacing `mc` with either `doublecmd-gtk` or `doublecmd-qt` in the command, if you wanted to.