# How can I install Midnight Commander on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, midnight-commander

I can't install Midnight Commander (`mc`) on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

And this is the reply I get when I try to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or 
 is only available from another source
```

This didn't help (#1):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

This didn't help (#2):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mc
```

It also didn't help to change mirror to `http://de.archive.ubuntu.com`, for example.

Comment: Also not working  apt-install ntp ...

Comment: I wonder why is this question closed? The other way to install mc would be by git cloning the repo from github, then running autoconf and ./configure. then make and make install...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to enable the `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and then install `mc`:

```
sudo apt install mc
```

Comment: `sudo apt update` is not necessary when adding a repo since it's initialized to latest contents.

Comment: When refreshing existing repos - yes, but when adding, it downloads the contents automatically. Just did it. But of course your answer is correct - +1!