# Midnight Commander in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, 20.04, midnight-commander

**Is there any precompiled Midnight Commander to have it running in Ubuntu 20.04LTS?**

I mean to avoid building from source.
I [did not find a Debian package](https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/Binaries) for it, or an executable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is an [`mc` package for 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mc) in the Ubuntu repositories, just like for previous versions. Simply install it using:

```
sudo apt install mc
```

If the command does not work for you, check you have [enabled the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/1071392/250300).

When you are looking for Ubuntu software, you should check https://packages.ubuntu.com/ as the first option.

Comment: I was forgetting the `update`.